# Can I extract portions of a php include?

Tags: php, css

Still learning php as I go so this might just be something I haven't gotten to yet but it's the next roadblock in building my personal site. I have a basic understanding of includes such as linking:

```
<a href="art.php?id=image id&name=This is my title&menu=side-menu-portfolio">
```

to pull my includes but I've come to a small problem in that my generic art-gallery page needs to switch between a 'portfolio' header and an 'artwork' header. So I figured I could either build "**art-gallery.php**" AND "**port-gallery.php**" and go back and relink everything or just make it so that when you call the link like the above code I just specify which header goes with it. Unfortunately this would also require going back and changing every link. But I noticed that I did state:

```
...&menu=side-menu-portfolio...
```

and the pages are already calling side-menu-artwork or side-menu-portfolio so if I could just call in menu and cast aside the 'side-menu-" portion then it would just use artwork or portfolio and call the right header. Unfortunately this is where my limited knowledge of php and syntax come in. I have tried to produce the following code based on my php and js understanding:

```
<?php include("headlines/headline-" . $_GET[menu - "side-menu-" ]  . ".php"); ?>
```

but I don't know if my syntax is just wrong or if what I'm trying to do is impossible to begin with. Note that when I try this I get

> **Function Include** error of **"Warning: include(headlines/headline-.php)"**

so it looks like everything else is reading correctly, I just don't know if or how I can extract the word I want from the rest of the menu name.

Comment: `$_GET[menu - "side-menu-" ]` does not seem like a valid variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be, Assumed your included file name is `headline-side-menu-portfolio.php`

```
 <?php 
     $filename = str_replace("side-menu-", "", $_GET['menu']); // headline-portfolio
    include("headlines/headline-" .  $filename  . ".php"); // headline-portfolio.php
 ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that was my problem.
It is titled headline-portfolio so I was hoping I could drop the side-menu- portion

Comment: Updated my answer, can you please check

Comment: Ok, I think I'm following and if so this might be exactly what I need. For my knowledge, can you clue me into what ("side-menu-", "", $_GET['menu']) does? I get the str_replace but what is going on inside the parenthesis?

Comment: So `$_GET['menu']` value is `-side-menu-portfolio`, but you need `portfolio` from the menu value, So str_replace function replaces the unwanted string that we specifiy in the function

Comment: Awesome - it worked perfectly and thanks for the info on the functionality as well!

Answer (score 0):

okay....your are almost there....just `quotes` missing from `include` syntax...it should be

```
include("headlines/headline-.php"); /* notice the quotes*/
```

so it should be

```
<?php include("headlines/headline-" .$_GET['menu'].".php"); ?>
```

where `$_GET['menu']` should be in the url, like:

`art.php?id=image id&name=This-is-my-title&menu=side-menu-portfolio`

**so what's happening her ??**

Upon execution of the line :

`<?php include("headlines/headline-" .$_GET['menu'].".php"); ?>`

`$_GET` is fetched from the url and replaced in the `header` tag, so now the `header` tag becomes :

`<?php include("headlines/headline-"."side-menu-portfolio".".php"); ?>` =>  
`<?php include("headlines/headline-side-menu-portfolio.php"); ?>`

Also. may i suggest that for :

```
<a href="art.php?id=image id&name=This is my title&menu=side-menu-portfolio">
```

don't use `space` in the url, either replace it by `-` or `_`

Comment: Or to make it clear that `include` is not a function but a language construct just `include 'headlines/headline-.php';`

Comment: I think I follow what you two are indicating - while php can put together the path to the php file I want I'm trying to make it preform the task of subtracting content which php isn't built to do. Is that correct?

If that's correct, is there an alternate route using php or will I have to involve js for this?

Comment: i really didn't understood what you asked.....but still will try to explain....editing the answer...wait!! :)

Comment: can you just check- **so what's happening her ??** and let me know what you want to do now??

Comment: @user1311848 :  since you are using `$_GET[]`, look for `strip_tags` feature too...else your page would be very easy to hack!! :)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my description - most of the responses were similar so I'm fault myself on this and try to fix it for the record when I can. What you had is What's Happening Here is what I was going for and I had been using in the other includes but in this case I was trying to remove the "side-menu-" portion of the 'menu" name that was passed along. My two files are "side-menu-portfolio" and "headline-portfolio" and I was hoping that if there was a way to negate the "side-menu- portion and pass along "portfolio" ONLY then I would produce "header-portfolio.php" as a result

Comment: haha...this should have been your first question...anyways...`$_GET` values are always vulnerbale to XSS attacks...so use `strip_tag` and `htmlencode` to secure your page! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
<?php include("headlines/headline-" . $_GET["menu"].".php"); ?>
<!--gives include("headlines/headline-side-menu-portfolio.php")-->
```

where

```
$_GET["menu"] = 'side-menu-portfolio'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php include("headlines/headline-" . $_GET['menu']  . ".php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

Instead of

`<?php include("headlines/headline-" . $_GET[menu - "side-menu-" ]  . ".php"); ?>`

try

`<?php include("headlines/headline-" . $_GET['menu'] . ".php"); ?>`

You should check if the file exists before you try including it.

`if (file_exists($filesrc)) { ... }`

Better yet **don't** let the user change the menu through a `$_GET` variable. Instead link to a specific page or pass a variable *then* decide what menu to get. Like

```
switch ($_GET['menu']) {
    case 'side-menu':
        include("headlines/headline-side-menu.php");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$_GET['menu']
```

, the "side-menu-" part is already in the content of your variable passed as param.

Comment: I think I worded it incorrectly in the initial question - "side-menu-" is not part of the header I am calling but part of the sidebar I am already calling. I was hoping to drop the "side-menu-" portion so that only the "portfolio" part was used in the include. My fault

Answer (score 0):

You propably want to do an `if .... else` so to include one header or another based on the $_GET variable `menu`.

So something like this will do this:

```
if($_GET['menu'] == 'side-menu-portfolio') {
    include 'headliens/side-menu-portfolio.php';
} elseif($_GET['menu'] == 'side-menu-other') {
    include 'headliens/side-menu-other.php';
}
```